# dateformatter producing wrong result on converting datefromstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

My string is `strDate:04/12/2016` on converting it to date in format dd/MM/yyyy. It is producing another format.it is producing result as `weekEndDate:2016-12-04 00:00:00 +0000`. My code is

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
weekEndDate=[formatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

Comment: nsdate is always irregular format

Comment: i have set the min date of date picker to Current date in xib , but when i scroll date picker to the previous dates it returns back to the current date but after that which ever date i select it shows i day before date. e.g like after scrolling to previous dates i select date 21 dec but the result is giving 20 Dec and its only in the case if i scroll date picker to previous dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2016-12-04 00:00:00 +0000

This is not a wrong format, whenever you will print an object of `NSDate` in your debugger that object will be printed like the above string i.e. in UTC timezone, if you want to check correct format then convert this date object in string and print that string you will get correct format.

Comment: i am converting this date from string in format dd/MM/yyyy but still date is in yyyy-MM-dd, is it correct ?

Comment: Yes this is correct, NSDate doesn't know any format it will always get printed like this.

Comment: i have set the min date of date picker to Current date in xib , but when i scroll date picker to the previous dates it returns back to the current date but after that which ever date i select it shows i day before date. e.g like after scrolling to previous dates i select date 21 dec but the result is giving 20 Dec and its only in the case if i scroll date picker to previous dates.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that you get that format, if you want to get your weekend date using that formatter here is how you do it :

```
NSString *strDate = @"04/12/2016";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *weekEndDate = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:weekEndDate]); // 04/12/2016
NSLog(@"%@", weekEndDate); // 2016-12-04 00:00:00 +0000
```